# Exploting a Stack Buffer Overflow vulnerability to get privilege access to system

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, c, centos

I am trying to complete a buffer overflow challenge. The code I am trying to exploit is below. I can only use the command line in a Linux environment.

I understand that writing more than 100 characters into "userString" will start to overwrite "command". My guess is that I need to somehow overwrite command with "/bin/sh" to launch into shell. I don't know exactly how to do that.

I've tried exceeding the input buffer to see what happens and I get this error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file 
Segmentation fault
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        char command[100];
        char userString[100];
        printf("Input a string to echo: ");
        gets(userString);
        snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "echo \"%s\"", userString);
        setresuid(502,502,502);
        system(command);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any exploitation of the C part, and it wouldn't help anyway (at least, just filling `command` wouldn't help). Whether overflowing `userString` will fill `command` depends on the order in which the compiler places the two variables. Even if `userString` is first, the `snprintf` call will overwrite `command` anyway.

The program runs `echo "%s"` where `%s` is the string you type. It's easy to make this run arbitrary code. One way is to insert a closing quote:

```
"; cat /secret; echo "
```

Another way, since these are double quotes, is to use a command substitution:

```
$(cat /secret)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't understand how to use those commands to launch me into a shell. Can you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: @TravisTaylor The `system` function is what launches you into a shell. What I show in my answer is what to pass as input to the program so that the shell executes something useful. I took `cat /secret` as an example. If you want a shell where you can type more commands, you can replace that by `bash`, for example.